# node-google-image-search error message 'Invalid Value'

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, search-engine, google-custom-search

I am making a node app which can return google images, I'm using the [`node-google-image-search`](https://github.com/jjmax75/google-image-search) app to help me do this. I created a .env file named "env.env" and imported the app with

```
const imageSearch = require('node-google-image-search');
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config({path: './env.env'});
```

Then I tried to search something with the following code.

```js
var results = imageSearch('google', callback, 0, 5);

function callback(results) {
    console.log(results);
}
```

This caused me to get the following error in the console:

`[ { domain: 'global', reason: 'invalid', message: 'Invalid Value' } ]`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your account is set up correctly to use Google Custom Search  and that you have the correct keys in your .env file?

Maybe worth just using [Google's customsearch example](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/samples/customsearch/customsearch.js) than using a separate module.

Comment: Tried this. I downloaded the zip and the example didn't work. I then installed googleapis into my app and it still gives me the same error of "Invalid Value"